# Server does not have internet access

Tags: windows-server-2012, routing

My Windows Server 2012 network adapter is configured like this:

[image]

192.168.144.1 is my router address.  From that same server this is the result of `tracert google.com`:

[image]

The server's name is "VQ40DE" and it is on the domain "poconoacademy.org". It's weird that it's trying to use itself as the first hop to google.com, and stranger still that it is "unreachable".

From a desktop machine connected to the same domain the first hop of `tracert google.com` is to the router, 192.168.144.1, which then continues to route internet traffic correctly.

What do I have misconfigured here?

```
Interface List
 12...c8 60 00 32 27 6c ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.144.1   192.168.144.12    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    192.168.144.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
   192.168.144.12  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
  192.168.144.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.144.12  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.144.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

From a desktop computer everything works as it should:

[image]

After removing the persistent route for 192.168.144.12:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.144.1   192.168.144.12    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    192.168.144.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
   192.168.144.12  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
  192.168.144.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.144.12    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.144.1  Default

Tracing route to google.com [172.217.1.14]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1  VQ40DE.PoconoAcademy.org [192.168.144.12]  reports: Destination host unreac
hable.

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Let's see your routing table. `ROUTE PRINT` for a start.

Comment: Do you have DHCP enabled in your network? If so try enable it on this server and take note the DNS server then.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I've updated the question to include the routing table.

Comment: Are other devices on the same subnet able to access the internet,  what is your gateway?  Do you have a nat policy configured for outbound traffic from this subnet?

Comment: @JacobEvans Yes, other devices use DHCP and are working correctly.  DHCP devices use 192.168.144.12 for DNS, which is the server that is having trouble routing internet traffic for itself.

Comment: Do you have multiple DNS servers? Also, could you please run `ipconfig /all` from the desktop that is working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the below entry under **Persistent Routes** is causing the trouble.

> 0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.144.12  Default

Delete it using route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.144.12 and try.

Comment: I've done that, but the server still can't access the internet.  Do I need to restart the machine or do something else to refresh the routing table?

Comment: i dont think a reboot is necessary. Can share the current outputs of "route print" and "tracert google.com"..!?

Comment: My question is updated with the current routing and tracert results at the bottom.

Comment: you still have an entry in your routing table "0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.144.12". Delete it using the command "route delete –p 0.0.0.0 ON-LINK". Check the below links for more clarification. http://superuser.com/questions/59996/what-does-on-link-mean-on-the-result-of-route-print-command https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3f157cfa-25a3-4a8f-859b-c1b94eb273d3/network-issue-default-gateway-become-onlink?forum=w7itpronetworking

Comment: When I ran the command `route delete –p 0.0.0.0 ON-LINK` I got this error: `route: bad argument ON-LINK`

Comment: try "route delete 0.0.0.0" and then add the required route using "route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.144.1".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42685/discussion-between-varun-and-yuck).

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Do find out the root cause why the entries where getting added to the routing table at the first place.

Answer (score -3):

You should try using google DNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) in the preferred DNS server field.

Router address (192.168.144.1) would act as a gateway on this server.

Comment: `VQ40DE` (the server in question) is running DNS for the domain.  That's why the primary DNS is set up as the localhost lookupback IP (127.0.0.1).  I tried setting 8.8.8.8 as the DNS for the IPv4 adapter but it can't route traffic to that IP, so DNS stops working.

Comment: More to the point I think is that DNS is not the problem.  With the server using 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.144.1 for DNS I am able to resolve host names.  The trouble is in the routing, as you can see where `tracert` fails to get to the router (192.168.144.1) for normal traffic.

Comment: DNS is obviously working.